# Bundling a React app with Gulp and Browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify

I am trying to bundle a simple React.js app using Gulp and Browserify but it's erroring while trying to find a module.

The gulp is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify('./app/index.js', {
        debug: false, bundleExternal: true
    })
    .transform(babelify, {"presets": ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
});
```

The index.js file is:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import routes from 'config/routes'
import users from 'redux/modules/users'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const store = createStore(users, applyMiddleware(thunk))

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {routes}
  </Provider>,
document.getElementById('app'))
```

The folder structure of the app is:

```
app/
  config/
   - routes.js
  components/
   - component folders + js
  index.js => imports all the other .js modules

gulpfile.babel.js
```

The error message is:

```
events.js:163
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

 Error: Cannot find module 'config/routes' from '/Users/tomv/Documents/Projects/base-react-project-pl/app'
```

It seems like Gulp isn't able to read the imports from the index.js file. Does anyone know what I may be missing?

Comment: I believe you should paste the code within `index.js` which is requiring the config/routes module. Maybe you're typing `require('config/routes')` instead of `require('./config/routes')`?

Comment: I've edited the original post with the index.js above.

Comment: switch to webpack it'll be easier I promise...

Comment: I got it working by adding the `add-module-export` plugin `es2015` preset in the Gulpfile.

Comment: I agree it would be easier to use webpack to get the app running, but I have to use Gulp and Browserify for the project.